# How can I get the Vulkan API working in Google Colab

Tags: vulkan, google-colaboratory

I tried running realsr-ncnn-vulkan to just test upscaling a simple image on Google's Colab platform.
https://github.com/nihui/realsr-ncnn-vulkan

The problem is that once I try to run it I'm getting the error

> error while loading shared libraries: libvulkan.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So what do I need to install prior before running it? Or is there no way to get vulkan working despite the pretty powerful GPU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the libraries:

depending on your setup you need:

```sh
dnf install vulkan-headers vulkan-loader-devel
```

or

```sh
apt-get install libvulkan-dev
```

or

```sh
pacman -S vulkan-headers vulkan-icd-loader
```

Comment: Thanks! 
apt install libvulkan-dev worked for me :)

Comment: After installing `libvulkan-dev` on GCP, Vulkan API does work, but the device is `llvmpipe` which means it's still using the CPU instead of the NVIDIA GPU...